# execute shell command on php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
$command = "ffmpeg -i '" . $img_full_name . "' -vf scale=200:200 '" . $img_thumb_name . "'" ;

    $output=shell_exec($command);   
    echo $output;
    die;
```

I am using this code to execute command in php but it gives me blank out put. Same command works if I Directly execute it on ssh.

Comment: Check the (relative) path to the file, try to answer what the processes current directory is.

Comment: Any error messages in the log files? Does the command terminate? How long does it run?

Comment: Another thing: are you sure `ffmpeg` can output to stdout? When looking through its man page it looks like it requires an output file to write the result to...